# Add a <a href> link outside each <li> in main menu

Tags: routes, theming

Right now I have images above each menu item (added in my CSS as background images assigned to a class in each list item) in my main menu. I would love to be able to have the image also as a link rather then just the text below it. To do so I need to have my entire list item as the link. I am pretty sure CSS can't do this and that I need to adjust my template.php, but I don't know enough about php just yet to be moving things around. Any help would be appreciated!

An example of what I would like:

```
<ul>
<a href="#">
   <li>About Us</li>
</a>
</ul>
```

Example of what I have:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="#">About Us</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And this is what I have in my template.php

```
<?php
function motg_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';
  $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;
$element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $element['#original_link']     ['mlid'];

  if ($element['#below']) {
$sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
 }

 if ($element['#original_link']['menu_name'] == "main-menu"){

$element['#title'] .= '<span class="description">'.$element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title'].'</span>';
}

$output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

Comment: what you are asking for is a wrong HTML structure.

Comment: What @junedkazi said. `<a>` is an inline element, `<li>` is a block element, and block elements can't go inside inline elements. If you're trying to make the entire `<li>` clickable just set a style of `display:block;` to the `<a>` tag inside it. That will make it fill the whole thing

Comment: Thanks guys. That's good to know and makes sense now. I  did what you said Clive and i'm good to go.